# Combining IF Matching Statements

Tags: list, if-statement, excel-formula, matching

Is there an easier way to put these two formulas together? I'm struggling. My two Formulas are

IF(MATCH(BASETRACKER!B2,'Code List Values'!V:V,0),"Reassign"))

and

=IF(F2="","",IF(MATCH(BASETRACKER!F2,'Code List Values'!E:E,0),"PRIVATE"))

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data its hard to tell what you are trying to do but maybe one of these could help?

```
=IF(MATCH(BASETRACKER!B2,'Code List Values'!V:V,0),"Reassign",IF(F2="","",IF(MATCH(BASETRACKER!F2,'Code List Values'!E:E,0),"PRIVATE")))

=IF(MATCH(BASETRACKER!B2,'Code List Values'!V:V,0),"Reassign"))+IF(F2="","",IF(MATCH(BASETRACKER!F2,'Code List Values'!E:E,0),"PRIVATE"))
```